# Geometric interpretation for p-series when $p=2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometry, simulation

It is known that
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac {1}{n^2}={\pi^2\over 6} $$

Is there any geometric interpretation for this series? In other words, is there any way to visually showcase this result elegantly?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls